# Vue - error loading assets and chunks when app.js has query params

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, single-spa

I'm working on an frontend application with multiple Vue 2 apps, using [single-spa framework](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/4.x/ecosystem-vue/).

The build from each Vue app is outputted to dist/ folder and then uploaded to a S3 bucket. The final structure is something like:

```
- app-one
      |- app.js
      |- js
          |- chunk1.js
          |- chunk2.js
      |- assets
          |- someimage.jpg

- app-two
      |- app.js
      |- js
          |- chunk1.js
          |- chunk2.js
      |- assets
          |- someimage.jpg
```

then an index.html loads the app.js from each Vue app through the single-spa (and each app.js loads the corresponding chunks - from lazy loaded imports - and assets). This works fine.

The problem is when we insert in the url from each app.js an query param, to avoid caching - the *old* timestamp pattern. Something like *app.js?v=324324*
where 324324 is the timestamp (it could be a version tag, a hash from the commit, whatever).

When the app.js loads, the final url in the browser is something like

> http://localhost:5000/app-one/app.js?v=324324

and each chunk (or asset) url is mounted like this:

> http://localhost:5000/app-one/?v=324324chunk-one.js

> http://localhost:5000/app-one/?v=324324myimage.png

It seems that Vue removes the app.js from the url and concatenate what is left with the chunk's (or asset's) name.

I have tried to change how webpack outputs assets and chunks but haven't found any relevant. I also took a look at [Vue's config documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/) but didn't found anything, too.

By the way, I know that the default approach is to append a hash in the app.js filename (such as app.389749234.js) but in our scenario, we prefer to keep the app.js so we do not need to rebuild the application with the single-spa that loads all off the microfrontends.

Comment: Another option would be to use the build ID as part of the deployment url. Eg. `https://company.cdn/static/s0m3h45h/app.js`

Comment: @filoxo if we do this, the single-spa app would have to change every time a microfrontend app is built, with the new url. It is the same scenario to use the hash in the app.js filename.

Comment: And its also the same scenario as appending a new timestamp to the end of the url, but then it won't conflict with the publicPath calculation.